# Maximal likelhood decoding in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Given a matrix `X` of size `(5,3)`, and a vector of `y` size `(1,3)`, I need to calculate the Euclidean distance of vector `y` to all vectors in `X` and return to the minimal.

For example

```
X =

    0.1338    0.0346    0.2961
    0.5320    0.4681    0.6784
    0.4484    0.5954    0.2847
    0.1437    0.5310    0.3946
    0.2854    0.0793    0.8621

y = 0.4484    0.5954    0.2847
```

So in that case, the minimal Euclidean distance of `y` is with row 3 in matrix `X`since it's the same.

I have made the code as below :

```
X = rand(5,3)                %The matrix x 
y = rand(1,3)                %The vector y

[~, size_y] = size(y)        %size of y
[size_x, ~] = size(X)        %size of matrix x 

min_distance = zeros(size_x,size_y);   %Initialize the minimal distance 

 %% Calculate minimum distance square of vector y to every vector in x

   for i = 1 : size_y
        min_distance(:,i) = sum(abs(repmat(y(:,i),1,size_x) - X).^2,2); 
end 

min_distance_1 = min_distance;
[index, ~] = (min(min_distance_1,[],1)); 

results = index - 1;
```

The results of that code is mismatch error,  however the index of row in matrix `X` which has the minimal Euclidean distance to vector `y` should be shown!!

Is there any mistake in code ? or how can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a few things missing in your code. For the Euclidean distance there should be a root somewhere. Also index is the second return value, not the first and there is no reason for -1 and an index in matlab.

There is a build in function to calculate the euclidean distance called `norm()`.  For your case where you want to calculate the distance to each vector there is a special [`vecnorm()`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vecnorm.html) thats fits perfectly.

```
differences = X-y 
%you dont need repmat but keep it if it helps your understanding of the code

distances = vecnorm(differences,2,2) 
%the first 2 is for 2-norm, which is Euclidean distance
%the second 2 for row-wise calculation

[~,index]= min(distances)
```